# Alternative Raspbian user interface for 3.5" 320x480 LCD TDT screen

Tags: raspbian, display, touchscreen, screen

I've got PI3 with 3.5" and 320x480 resolution. I'll mainly use the LCD with Synergy keyboard sharing for now and I wonder if there are any better alternatives of user environments that would let me fully appreciate Raspbian GUI as of right now some windows don't fit on the screen and do not allow resizing, etc.

What other environments I could use, while keeping Raspbian level community support and functionality?

Or how could I change the resolution that wouldn't be too broken?

Using Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and Kuman 3.5" LCD/TFT display.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't change the resolution. It is normally fixed on small screens like the one you have. I also don't know of any alternative window manager that is designed to improve the usefulness of such a small screen.

However, there are two alternatives:

1. You could use the command line with your small screen, or
2. Use SSH or VNC to forward command prompt or the GUI (respectively) to another machine.

You can switch which mode your Pi boots into GUI or terminal by using the raspi-config script. You can run it with the following command:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

You can also use the same script to enable SSH or VNC (assuming you are running a recent version of Raspbian Jessie). Details on configuring and using [SSH](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/) and [VNC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) can be found in the Pi Foundation's Pi documentation.

Comment: I think the Xorg server has most of the bottom line with regard to screen size; if that's correct then if you "maximize" a window the window manager should make it fit the screen.  Getting X to set the correct resolution may not be automatic or simple, though.  You can still use customized `xorg.conf` files but 'nuff said >_>  At least some window managers do allow independent setting of the resolution in some advisory sense, but I dunno how useful that is either.  Probably a hard thing to fine tune well.

Comment: @goldilocks It may allow some degree of configuration, but there is no getting around the fixed number of pixels. Any window that wants to use more than that will either not fit the screen or get scrollbars neither of which help the usability.

Comment: Yeah...I notice I cannot make chrome narrower than ~500px.   Things that can lose most of their menu bar if you do...  I would start working on this by finding out what's possible how with the apps I want to use on a normal desktop, and just give up on the ones that aren't going to work.  It's not a "wee mobile device" GUI.  It's a standard desktop one.   Customizing all that will never happen -- there may be resources out there to make Android versions of stuff (and this is pretty small pixel wise even for that), but "Pi TFT", don't hold yer breath.